# Link news stories from other SharePoint sites to my main umbrella site

Tags: newsfeed

Is it possible to link the news stories from other SharePoint sites to my main umbrella site? (i.e.: If I have a main site "Site A", can I feed it stories from Sites "B", "C", "D", and "E"?

That way, if used as an intranet, I can define local managers to produce news stories on their specialist subjects, but dont have to manually copy back to site A.

Do I have to define RSS settings for all the subsites and read them all on site A?

I am listed as the owner for all of the sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would think so if you use Search as a mean to show the news articles on the front page/ hub site. This also has the benefit that the content is security trimmed by default 
Using the content type hub to distribute your articles page will ensure easy updates and a fairly simple search setup